# Azure function zip deployment from storage account not working for remote build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

For a project I'm building an Azure function. The infrastructure is deployed using Terraform with CI/CD. We have a separate git repo where the azure function code lives. I can succesfully deploy the code from VScode when selecting the relevant azure resource.

Now I want to make it such that when I make a change to the azure function repository, the CI/CD pipeline automatically triggers the deployment on the azure function. To do this the repository is zipped (in the pipeline) and then uploaded to a storage account. For the azure function I have set the following settings, as well as some custom ones that are irrelevant and thus removed, using Terraform:

```
"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"       = "https://${var.storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/${var.storage_account_container_name}/cpms-function-app.zip${var.sas_token}",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME"       = "python",
"AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage"    = "true",
"SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT" = "true"
"ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD"              = "true"
```

Context: Python runtime (3.9) on Linux.
When deploying from the storage account it gives an error on that a module is not imported that is definitely included in the requirements. I have searched for hours on this and I'm lost on what would be the way to fix this. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies) this should be sufficient to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I tried:

- Deployment through other options, using different runtime/function versions
- Deployment in different regions
- Local testing (does not work due to ARM64 machine)

Note that I am able to get the files in there, it just doesn't seem to be able to build it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For [Remote Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#remote-build) to run you need to perform a [zip deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#zip-deploy) instead of doing Run from Package.

Another option that you can explore is [deploying a docker container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#docker-container) to ensure all dependencies are installed as required.